# How to read highlighted cell in excel using node JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, npm

I have written a node js script to read data from an excel file.
My scenario is each row will have a column that has a highlighted cell (only 1). Currently, I am using `xlsx` package to read the data. Below is my code by which I am reading data from the sheet:

```
var XLSX = require('xlsx')
var workbook = XLSX.readFile('Book1.xlsx');
var sheet_name = workbook.SheetNames;
var xlData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheet_name[0]]);
console.table(xlData);
```

and this is my sample data:

[image: excel]

How can I read the data of C3 from the above picture?
Or can anyone suggest me anyway without any package?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx-color

Comment: The `readFile` function apparently supports [`cellStyles: true`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx#parsing-options) in its options which saves style/theme info into the `.s` field - could try that.

Comment: @cbr can you get me a syntax of writing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation, you can pass `cellStyles` to the options when using `read` or `readFile`. This option adds the `.s` field to the cells, which contains the style.

You can then go through the cells and filter for cells which have `bgColor` in the style:

```
const XLSX = require('xlsx');
const workbook = XLSX.readFile('Book1.xlsx', {
  cellStyles: true
});
const sheet_name = workbook.SheetNames;
const sheet = workbook.Sheets[sheet_name[0]];

const cells = Object.entries(sheet).filter(([cell]) => !cell.startsWith('!'));
const coloredCells = cells.filter(([cell, value]) => value.s && value.s.bgColor);

for (const [cell, value] of coloredCells) {
  console.log(cell, value.w);
}
```

The `sheet` object which contains the cells seems to contain some metadata as keys which start with `!`, so those are filtered out.

The meat here however is this line:

```
cells.filter(([cell, value]) => value.s && value.s.bgColor);
```

It checks that the cell has a style property (`.s`) and that the style has a `bgColor`. I don't know if it's possible to set the background color explicitly to transparent or white, but in your example it seems to work. You could compare the color to the specific color you want, if there are cells with explicitly set white backgrounds.

I also make use of [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), some [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of).

Comment: Well this worked. But 1 thing I want to know can I use xlsx library to write cells using color?

Comment: Well, have you tried? Just set `.s.bgColor` to an appropriate value. Console.log the value to see what format it's in.